# EditText TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER doesn't accept input

Tags: android, android-edittext

The code below produces an `EditText`, but after the numeric only soft keyboard comes up, typing is not recognized.  If I change the `setInputType` to `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`, it works just right.  I've read and reread all the existing posts about this, but I don't see any where it refuses to accept the typing.

```
// And a zip code
        zip = Util.buildOneLine("ZIP");
        zip.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        zip.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "jkljl");
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "jkljl");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "jkljl");
            }
        });

 public static EditText buildOneLine(String heading)
{

    EditText bottomT = new EditText(this);
    bottomT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, adjustedFont(14));
    bottomT.setHint(heading);
    temp.setSingleLine(true);
    bottomT.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    setLayout(bottomT);


    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EditText is misbehaving because in my custom ViewGroup I had

```
 protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
....
     child.layout(child.getLeft(), child.getTop(),
                    child.getLeft() + child.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    child.getTop() + child.getMeasuredHeight());

     child.setRight(somevalue);   // CAUSES EDITTEXT PROBLEMS
     child.setBottom(somevalue);  // CAUSES EDITTEXT PROBLEMS
```

It’s clear now that I can't setRight() and setBottom(), but it’s also clear that EditText should not get weird.

Ignore the backspace key.

Randomly ignore numeric keys, but accept the decimal point.

Ignore the newLine(Enter) key

Which keys are ignored, or not, depends on the device.  Samsung Tab 4 or the Nexus 5 API 23 X86 emulator are good places to see this.

Answer (score 0):

**Well try this :**

```
zip.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER |InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look.  I should have mentioned that I already tried setRawInputType(......).  NO difference.

Comment: Johnrao07:  I appreciate that you're helping me find the issue.  InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL has strange results too.  It brings up the numeric keypad, which also has arithmetic symbols.  So I can press ./*+ and they are entered.  But if I press any of the numbers, they are thoroughly ignored.